# How can I migrate articles from one Joomla 2.5 installation to another Joomla 2.5 installation?

Tags: joomla, migration, articles

I want to move some articles from an existing J! 2.5.x installation to another J! 2.5.x installation. I have had a look in the extensions but there is not a non commercial component that does this.

Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: Install another copy of joomla, and overwrite all new tables?

Comment: Which tables would only encompass articles and categories?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a one-off migration of articles there are a few options available. We use a variety of extensions depending on the job requirements, they are all listed in the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)'s section for [Migration](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion).

Lately we've been using the [SP extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/owner/phalouvas) more as we've had good experiences with their tool for migrating clients sites from Joomla! 1.5 to 2.5.

We used their [SP Transfer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/19274) twice to migrate groups of articles where a client had decided to break their website up into several smaller sites.

We've also used [CSVI](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/19745) but that required a bit more manual work with respect to linked images and files.

Comment: SP is commercial. CSVI free edition only does VirtueMart. I need to do articles.

Comment: sorry missed 'non' - compared to the hours and hours of time it's saved us its minimal cost is a non-issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Migrate your Articles to Joomla 2.5 with J2XML](http://joomladirect.com/how-to-migrate-your-articles-to-joomla-2-5-with-j2xml/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you duplicate entire DB and remove articles you don't need? In case if another installation is fresh install.

From command line you can export and import DB:

```
$mysqldump -u root -p [dbname] > dbjoomla.sql

$mysql -u root -p -h localhost [dbname2] < dbjoomla.sql
```